# Facebook Auth in Canvas App: Internet Explorer redirects to index when clicking on links

Tags: facebook-graph-api, iframe, facebook-oauth, facebook-canvas

My Facebook App works fine in Firefox but behaves weird in IE when clicking on links: It redirects all the time and when clicking on a link within the iFrame it finally redirects back to the index.php without keeping the GET-Vars of the link. It seems that it always redirects to the authentification-URL.

This is the core part of my canvas page: index.php:

```
    <?

require 'facebook-php-sdk-6c82b3f/src/facebook.php';

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => 'XXX',
  'secret' => 'YYY',
));


function get_facebook_cookie($app_id, $application_secret) {
  $args = array();
  parse_str(trim($_COOKIE['fbs_' . $app_id], '"'), $args);
  ksort($args);
  $payload = '';
  foreach ($args as $key => $value) {
    if ($key != 'sig') {
      $payload .= $key . '=' . $value;
    }
  }
  if (md5($payload . $application_secret) != $args['sig']) {
    return null;
  }
  return $args;
}


$cookie = get_facebook_cookie('XXX',  'YYY');

// Get User ID
$user = $facebook->getUser();


if ($user) {
  try {
    // Proceed knowing you have a logged in user who's authenticated.
    $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
  } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    error_log($e);
    $user = null;
  }
}

?>


<body onload="self.focus();document.tips.tip0A.focus()" scroll="no" style="overflow:hidden">
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
        FB.init({ appId: 'XXX', status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true });
        FB.Canvas.setSize({ height: 890 });
    };
    (function () {
        var e = document.createElement('script');
        e.type = 'text/javascript';
        e.src = document.location.protocol +
            '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
        e.async = true;
        document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
    } ());
</script>


<?
if (!$user_profile[id]) {?>
<script>
  var oauth_url = 'https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth/';
  oauth_url += '?client_id=429812627032252';
  oauth_url += '&redirect_uri=' + encodeURIComponent('https://apps.facebook.com/euro_challenge/');
  oauth_url += '&scope=email,user_birthday'

  window.top.location = oauth_url;
</script>
<?}?>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?
    header("p3p: CP=\"ALL DSP COR PSAa PSDa OUR NOR ONL UNI COM NAV\"");
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Facebook recommends using a bogus P3P header just to make IE happy.  Be careful emitting a "real" P3P header as it implies you have a specific privacy policy in place.  It is not just random characters.

On this page http://developers.facebook.com/docs/samples/canvas/ of its developer documentation Facebook recommends:

```
P3P: CP="HONK"
```